# Comma after equation

Tags: notation

*ps: I have asked this question on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154339/comma-after-equation)) but is regarded as off-topic. So I moved it here.*

---

I have seen different ways in papers to put comma after equation.

1. right after the equation:

   [image]
2. right before `where`:

   [image]
3. no comma at all:

   [image]

**Which way should I choose? Which way is more standard?**

Comment: I wonder why they chose to move it here. I'm sure this is even described in Knuth

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Someone else suggested to move it here.

Comment: There are good answers on tex.se, even though the question is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first variant is correct (though this is a question on typography rather than math).
More precisely, if you would place a comma with non-display formulas (or if the formula where a normal sequene of words) the you also should place a comma with a display formula. The same holds for periods. However, in TeX you would set the comma or other interpunction after the single dollar ("`$a=b$, where`"), but before the double-dollar ("`$$a=b,$$ where`") for the very reason that variant two must be avoided. Sometimes switching from inline to display causes variant two by mistake.

Comment: What about the other two? Are they both wrong?

Comment: Variant 2 is quite horrible. I often end up using variant 3 myself, but technically, one should have a comma somewhere.

Comment: Variant 2 is really wrong as far as the term wrong applies to this kind of question. For variant 3 I must admit that the most prominent rule on English commas that I know is "If in doubt leave it out". But I guess there is a semantic difference between having a comma before "where" or not. I suggest to cross-check at http://english.stackexchange.com